# Glibc-2.22 make (infitite loop) error [LFS 7.8 - 6.9]

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, gnu-make, glibc, linux-from-scratch

This error appears when i try to compile glibc package in make pass of Chapter 6.9 - Linux from Scratch 7.8.
When make is running, it enters in an infinite loop which repeats the follow:

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../include/limits.h /usr/include/limits.h
gawk -f ../scripts/gen-as-const.awk ../sysdeps/x86_64/locale-defines.sym \
| gcc -S -o /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.hT3 -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline  -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=undef -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -g -Wstrict-prototypes     -ftls-model=initial-exec      -I../include -I/sources/glibc-2.22/build/string  -I/sources/glibc-2.22/build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu/include -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.   -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /sources/glibc-2.22/build/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -x c - \
    -MD -MP -MF /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h.dT -MT '/sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h.d /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h'
sed -n 's/^.*@@@name@@@\([^@]*\)@@@value@@@[^0-9Xxa-fA-F-]*\([0-9Xxa-fA-F-][0-9Xxa-fA-F-]*\).*@@@end@@@.*$/#define \1 \2/p' \
    /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.hT3 > /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.hT
rm -f /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.hT3
sed -e 's@ /sources/glibc-2\.22/build/@ $(common-objpfx)@g' -e 's@^/sources/glibc-2\.22/build/@$(common-objpfx)@g' -e 's@  *\.\.\/\([^  \]*\)@ $(..)\1@g' -e 's@^\.\.\/\([^     \]*\)@$(..)\1@g' \
    /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h.dT > /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h.dT2
rm -f /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h.dT
mv -f /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h.dT2 /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h.d
mv -f /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.hT /sources/glibc-2.22/build/locale-defines.h
```

Does someone an idea about how to solve this?
Someone told me that is a common error when build system clock isn't set right. However this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know the reason for the loop, but you can diagnose it a bit more by running:

```
make -d |& tee log
less log
```

this will be very verbose, but buried in there should be lines that say something like `xxx is newer than locale-defines.h; must remake locale-defines.h`.  you can perhaps use that to track down the loop.

there is also the [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) program which can provide a bit more user friendly debug output.  many distros include that already.

note about broken clock settings: if your clock was broken at one point in time, simply fixing it right now does not mean all `make` calls after that point will work.  you usually need to completely remove the source/build directories and restart the build process from scratch.